# sometimes Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: 12.04, server, mysql

I've got my application up and running, with rails on my ubuntu VPS in Linode with mysql.

here's the version of mysql:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

It all generally work fine, except that, sometimes when I open a new rails console I get the following error:

```
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.16/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
```

and from them all attempts to enter the console fail. why the application still works fine and it's still using the database.

If I do in a shell:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
 * MySQL is stopped.
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld ... [ OK ] 
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld ... [fail]
```

but the application keeps working fine all the time.

The `/var/log/mysql/error.log` was empty before these three commands, after them I read:

```
140510 19:14:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140510 19:14:32 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140510 19:14:32 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140510 19:14:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140510 19:14:32 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
140510 19:14:32  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
..... several thousands of these lines... 
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
140510 19:16:12  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
140510 19:16:12  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140510 19:16:12 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140510 19:16:12 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140510 19:16:12 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140510 19:16:12 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140510 19:16:12 [ERROR] Aborting

140510 19:16:12 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140510 19:16:12 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Only rebooting the VPS seems to solve the issue, which comes back after one or two console connections.

I figured that shutting down Mysql from `init.d` doesn't shut it down, to stop it I need to `kill` it, then it automatically respawns.

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysq[l]
mysql    31063     1  0 May19 ?        00:00:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ] 
$ ps -ef | grep mysq[l]
mysql    31063     1  0 May19 ?        00:00:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
$ sudo kill -9 31063
$ ps -ef | grep mysq[l]
mysql     6052     1  3 09:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
$
```

any clue?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because mysql could not start whiling booting up.

## Try this remedy

/etc/init.d/mysqld restart

## or try this

Remove basedir attribute from /etc/my.cnf file

## Why?

The basedir directive instructs MySQL where to find everything it needs to function: binaries, libraries, data, etc. Hence by stipulatingbasedir=/var/lib, MySQL will search /var/lib for everything needed to perform its functions.

For typical installs via RPM, this directive is not needed and should not be used. For a more exhaustive description of this directive, please consult the MySQL manual.

## note

I infact once faced this issue due to memory issue as well.
Try and check for free memory as well.

## Reference URL

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` I tried too, and it doesn't improve the situation.

Comment: Sorry I just figured that there was a "part two" in your answer, I've tried commenting out the `basedir` attribute in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, and then restarting mysql, I still got a fail. any more ideas?

Comment: Check out the link i just posted